# Remove part from dynamic url and redirect

Tags: url-rewriting, redirect, tags, rewrite-rules

How do can I redirect the following URL to the next URL? It essentially should remove the ID part (this is a post tag URL).

`http://wpsoup.test/tag/88/koffie/` -> `http://wpsoup.test/tag/koffie/`.

I've tried the following code functions to reverse create the URLs (they're from a website that uses an SPA as frontend and WordPress as backend, which means I need to reverse this behaviour because most, if not all, posts have a link with these kind of URLs), but they are not working (even after permalink flush). Is it only possible to do this with `.htaccess`?

```php
function replace_tag_link($taglink, $tag_id) {
    $tag = get_tag($tag_id);
    $tag_name = $tag->slug;
    return str_replace($taglink, $tag_name, "$tag_id/$tag_name");
}
add_filter('tag_link', 'replace_tag_link', 10, 2);

// and...

function replace_tag_link($qv) {
    if (array_key_exists('tag', $qv)) {
        $tag = get_term_by('name', $qv['tag'], 'post_tag');
        $qv['tag'] = "{$tag->term_id}/{$qv['tag']}";
    }
}
add_filter('request', 'replace_tag_link', 10, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it with the following code:

```php
/**
 * Redirect '/tag/[0-9]/{tag_name}/' to the correct tag.
 */
add_filter('request', function($qv) {
    if (array_key_exists('category_name', $qv) && preg_match('/(tag\/)([0-9]*)/', $qv['category_name'])) {
        $qv = [
            'tag' => $qv['name']
        ];
    }

    return $qv;
});
```

I'm not sure if this is the right way, but it works!